# SSL force URL Rewrite

Tags: rewrite

I'm trying to force a specific URL to use HTTPS, but the problem is that all the links in that page would point to HTTPS of other pages as well.

So, I was thinking about updating my virual host file like this.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    #Rewrite urls under /foo/bar/* to use HTTPS://domain/foo/bar/*
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^/foo/bar/(.*) https://domain/foo/bar/$1
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    #Rewrite all urls except /foo/bar/* to use HTTP://domain/*  
</VirtualHost>
```

Any suggestions on how I can implement this?

Answer (score 0):

You should add the [R,L] flags to the rule.  L may be redundant since it is the only rule, but if you add other rules later, the L keeps it from running any more rules if this rule handles the request.  R makes it a redirection, so the client is actually sent a redirection command to the https:// site.

For the :443 virtualhost, you'll need to use RewriteCond to exclude cases where the path is /foo/bar/*

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/foo/bar/
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ http://domain/$1 [R,L]
```

This basically says if the REQUEST_URI does NOT begin with /foo/bar/, then redirect to http://

Comment: Thanks man. How can I add this to `.htaccess`?

Comment: Since there's no `<VirtualHost *:443>` I tried adding `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on` to the existing condition but no luck.